# How to retrieve localStorage data using javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I was trying to retrieve all the all the localStorage.setItem() that I set but I was not successful at this time.

This is my code

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: base_url + '/demo/now',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

        localStorage.setItem('visitor_info', JSON.stringify(data.visitor_info));
        localStorage.setItem('visitor_country', data.visitor_country);
        localStorage.setItem('phone2', data.phone2);
        localStorage.setItem('countryUrl', data.countryUrl);
    }
});
```

right now I'm successful in saving it to localStorage, but I don't know how to retrieve all this.

This is my code for retrieving it.

```
function localStorageGetItem() {
    localStorage.getItem('visitor_country');
    localStorage.getItem('phone2');
    localStorage.getItem('countryUrl');

    return "blank so far"
}
```

I know I need to put value in return but I'm not sure how to return all these 3 getItem.

and this is where I need to call the localStorageGetItem()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    localStorageGetItem();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you can't get it until you set it ... ajax is asynchronous ... this may be your problem

Comment: You want to return all three values from LocalStorage? Just return them in an array or object then.

Comment: Looks like the code is correct.  Make sure you are setting the data correctly before retrieving.

Comment: @poushy Apart from the `getItem` calls doing nothing.

Comment: oh I forgot to say all 3 localStorage.getItem() is inside the method named localStorageGetItem() {}, that's why I need to put value in return

Comment: I'll update the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, it sounds like you simply want to return an object with properties matching some of the keys stored in `localStorage`.

```
function localStorageGetItem() {
  return {
    visitor_country: localStorage.getItem('visitor_country'),
    phone2: localStorage.getItem('phone2'),
    countryUrl: localStorage.getItem('countryUrl')
  }
}
```

You can then use it like this...

```
var localData = localStorageGetItem();
console.log(localData.visitor_country); // etc
```

Keep in mind, each of these properties will be `null` if you call this before the data is stored via `localStorage.setItem`.

Answer (score -1):

> I know I need to put value in return but I'm not sure how to return all these 3 getItem.

You can assign these into a new object or fetch them via localStorage as you did, since its a global property.

But the problem why you cann't revieve them is answered by Jaromanda X

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;
var myStorage = {}
$.when($.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: base_url + '/demo/now',
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data) {

    localStorage.setItem('visitor_info', JSON.stringify(data.visitor_info));
    localStorage.setItem('visitor_country', data.visitor_country);
    localStorage.setItem('phone2', data.phone2);
    localStorage.setItem('countryUrl', data.countryUrl);
    myStorage = localStorage

}
})).then(console.log(myStorage));
```

Comment: What’s the purpose of `myStorage`?